# How to refactor repeated Golang codebase usage of pointer

Tags: go

What is the best way to refactor repeated code base like below? I looked at a few different methods on Golang but wasn't able to find something useful quickly. I'm also using `go-restful` package with Swagger

```
func (api ApiResource) registerLostLogin(container *restful.Container) {
    ws := new(restful.WebService)
    ws.
        Path("/lostlogin").
        Doc("Lost login").
        Consumes(restful.MIME_JSON, restful.MIME_XML).
        Produces(restful.MIME_JSON, restful.MIME_JSON) // you can specify this per route as well

    ws.Route(ws.POST("").To(api.authenticate).
        Doc("Performs lost login actions").
        Operation("lostlogin").
        Reads(LostLogin{})) // from the request

    container.Add(ws)
}

func (api ApiResource) registerAccount(container *restful.Container) {
    ws := new(restful.WebService)
    ws.
        Path("/account").
        Doc("Account calls").
        Consumes(restful.MIME_JSON, restful.MIME_XML).
        Produces(restful.MIME_JSON, restful.MIME_JSON) // you can specify this per route as well

    ws.Route(ws.POST("").To(api.authenticate).
        Doc("Register calls").
        Operation("register").
        Reads(Account{}))

    ws.Route(ws.PUT("").To(api.authenticate).
        Doc("Modify user details").
        Operation("modifyUserDetails").
        Reads(Account{}))

    ws.Route(ws.PUT("security").To(api.authenticate).
        Doc("Modify security question").
        Operation("modifySeucirtyQuestion").
        Reads(Account{}))

    ws.Route(ws.PUT("limit").To(api.authenticate).
        Doc("Modify limit").
        Operation("modifyLimit").
        Reads(Account{}))

    ws.Route(ws.PUT("password").To(api.authenticate).
        Doc("Modify password").
        Operation("modifyPassword").
        Reads(Account{}))

    container.Add(ws)
}

func main() {
    // to see what happens in the package, uncomment the following
    restful.TraceLogger(log.New(os.Stdout, "[restful] ", log.LstdFlags|log.Lshortfile))

    wsContainer := restful.NewContainer()
    api := ApiResource{map[string]intapi.OxiResp{}}
    api.registerLogin(wsContainer)
    api.registerAccount(wsContainer)
    api.registerLostLogin(wsContainer)
    api.registerWallet(wsContainer)

    config := swagger.Config{
        WebServices:     wsContainer.RegisteredWebServices(), // you control what services are visible
        WebServicesUrl:  "http://localhost:8080",
        ApiPath:         "/apidocs.json",
        SwaggerPath:     "/apidocs/",
        SwaggerFilePath: "/Users/aa/IdeaProjects/go_projects/src/test1/src/swagger-ui/dist",
        DisableCORS:     false}
    swagger.RegisterSwaggerService(config, wsContainer)

    log.Printf("start listening on localhost:8080")
    server := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080", Handler: wsContainer}
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

My main concern is duplication around all ws being duplicated across. Is it better if I use deference operator and pointer for the receiver with ApiResource?

Comment: How are you calling these? Sequentially? I would wrap it with another function and pass it in... If not, does the package have an interface you can wrap in your own type and implement?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead these are called sequentially. I just wanted to find out whether it's possible to wrap with `function literal` with function wrappers but I thin your suggestion also makes sense. I just wanted to find out if there's any Go specific way of implementing this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly wrap them up.. perhaps something like this:

```
type registration func(container *restful.Container, ws *restul.WebService)

func registerHandlers(handlers ...registration) {
    c := restful.NewContainer()
    ws := new(restful.WebService)

    for _, h := range handlers {
        h(c, ws)
    }
}
```

Then call it, passing in all of your methods:

```
api := ApiResource{map[string]intapi.OxiResp{}}

registerHandlers(api.registerLostLogin, 
                 api.registerAccount)
```

Then you just need to accept the `WebService` instance in your methods:

```
 func (api ApiResource) registerAccount(container *restful.Container, ws *restful.WebService)
```

That at least re-uses the `WebService` instance across method calls. A little bit more code though.

Comment: Please excuse my backwards variadic method arguments. I had post `...` instead of pre `...`. Fixed now.

Comment: No problem at all. Happy Gophering! :)

Comment: Golang is awesome. I don't know why people want to use Nodejs instead!

Comment: Another thing, do I need to pass in deference operator `*ApiResource` in the receiver instead? Is it better than copying?

Comment: I can't really speak to that given that I can't see what `ApiResource` is/does. Having said that, it _sounds_ like its big enough to warrant a pointer receiver, as it sounds like it manages its own state. So, I would say "yes" to using `*ApiResource`.

Comment: Great thanks. By the way I'm getting `undefined: registration` error. Do I need to define registration func?

Comment: Yes.. see the very first line of code in my answer? You need that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61624/discussion-between-simon-whitehead-and-passionate-developer).

Comment: Silly typo by me. The answer is fixed (spelling mistake!)